# Access Denied making image public on s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded an image to my bucket on s3 and when I try to make the image public from within the same account I get an access denied.  I'm relatively new to AWS, but I used my account to upload it and it even lists me as the owner of the bucket/image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the bucket has **Block Public Access** applied by default. You can turn it off on the bucket, or for all buckets.

See: [Amazon S3 Block Public Access – Another Layer of Protection for Your Accounts and Buckets | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/)